# wordpress add individual genre archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress, and was wanting to know how I would add 22 individual genre types &/or archives to wordpress, as I am coding a movie website.

Also I have added a custom post type 'movies' and want to add the 22 genres as 22 tick boxes to the UI.

Thanks in advance
Steven

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: I wasn't asking for free code writing service as I knew how to add the taxonomies, I just wanted to know what was the best way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [register_taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy). But I don't think that you should register 22 deifferent categories. You can register one ( genre ) for example and add those 22 different genres. If can register as much as you want new categories/taxonomies. Once registered that taxonomy in edit movie page is right sidebar you will find your genres.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'genre', # Taxonomy name
    array( 'movies' ), # Post Types
    array( # Arguments
        'labels'            => array(
            'name'              => __( 'Genres', 'crb' ),
            'singular_name'     => __( 'Genre', 'crb' ),
            'search_items'      => __( 'Search Genres', 'crb' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Genres', 'crb' ),
            'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Genre', 'crb' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Genre:', 'crb' ),
            'view_item'         => __( 'View Genre', 'crb' ),
            'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Genre', 'crb' ),
            'update_item'       => __( 'Update Genre', 'crb' ),
            'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Genre', 'crb' ),
            'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Genre Name', 'crb' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Genres', 'crb' ),
        ),
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
    )
);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. will I be able to use WP_Query to count the amount of horror movies I have ? and if so you are amazin :)

Comment: Well you can do almost anything using wordpress, and yes, you can see the amount of movies. 

For some reason I can't add the image here, so here is a link how it looks. There is a column count that show the number of movies associated with that genre.
https://cldup.com/KIhLqzkSKO-2000x2000.png